# How to install a package and save the setting?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I created a new project using `stack`.

```
stack new myproj
```

I want to install a package `lens`. If I use the following command, the package will be installed, but it's not being added to `package.yml`

```
stack install lens
```

The problem is that if I sync the code somewhere else, and run `stack install`, `lens` won't be installed.

Is there something similar to what nodejs provides, like `npm install --save lens`, so that `stack install --save lens` will automatically add `lens` into `package.yml`

Comment: If you add lens to your package.yaml then do `stack install`, it will automatically install the dependencies first, so if you sync it to another machine along with the package.yaml, it will always install lens if needed.

Answer (score 0):

This has not been implemented yet in Stack.

This is the relevant issue for it: https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/1933